# Can Micronaut Circuit Breakers be skipped for some HTTP status codes?

Tags: micronaut, circuit-breaker, micronaut-client

Is there a way to configure the Micronaut Circuit Breaker so that it is not opened for specific HTTP status codes? If I for instance do a lookup on an item and that item is not found, then a server might return HTTP status 404. This might be a perfectly valid response, and I do not want the circuit breaker to open in these cases.

As far as I understand the Micronaut circuit breaker is not tied to HTTP, but there is still a solution that nearly gets me there:

```
@Client("${myEndpoint}")
@CircuitBreaker(attempts = "4", predicate = ServerErrorRetryPredicate.class)
public interface MyClient {
    @Get
    Single<MyItem> getItem(int itemId);
}

public class ServerErrorRetryPredicate implements RetryPredicate {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof HttpClientResponseException) {
            HttpClientResponseException e = (HttpClientResponseException) throwable;
            return e.getStatus().getCode() >= 500;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here I am using the new Predicate that came with Micronaut 2, and in this case the predicate fails if the HTTP status is less than 500 (so it will fail for a HTTP status 404 that I get when the item is not found). This works perfectly well for avoiding retries, but it has no effect on circuit breakers.

Is it possible to avoid opening a circuit breaker based on the result of the predicate, like retry is skipped based on it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking on `DefaultRetryInterceptor`, the circuit breaker is opened when an exception is produced.
Also micronaut [http client](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientError) will always throws an error for 404 response (except for blocking clients) which will trigger the circuit breaker.

The `predicate`, `excludes` and `includes` fields of `@CircuitBreaker` seem to be used only for the retry feature.